# "plug and play" hdd (Arch linux)

Tags: linux, external-hard-drive, arch-linux

I'm using Arch linux. I have a sata HDD that i use as storage disk. It's always off until i need it. Then i plug it into (running) computer and with Windows 7 it's easy - i just go to the "Management" and "Rescan disks" -> voila! My disk is ready for use.

Is there a (simple) way to do something like that in Arch? To just plug my sata hdd whenever i need it, run some simple program that will detect my disk and later just unmount it and unplug it without ever reseting / logout?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linux, SATA disks should be detected automatically, without having to rescan them explicitly – check the kernel log in `dmesg` for details.

When the disk is detected, use `mount` and `umount`, or their GUI alternatives (such as GNOME Disk Utility), to mount the filesystems contained in that disk.

---

If necessary, you could try triggerring a manual rescan of SCSI & SATA devices with:

```
echo "0 0 0" | tee /sys/class/scsi_host/host*/scan
```

Check the Linux ATA pages *[Driver status](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Hardware,_driver_status)* and *[Hardware features](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/SATA_hardware_features)* if something does not work.

Make sure your SATA controller is actually running in AHCI mode instead of "IDE compatibility".

Also make sure you are running the same kernel as is installed. If you install a newer kernel but forget to reboot, the old kernel will be unable to load new modules if they become necessary.

Comment: No, my disk is not automatically recognized (not even by Gnome disk utility). When i try to execute above cmd i get "tee: /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/scan: Permission denied" even if i run it as root... :\ I don't even see new "sdc" (i allready have sda and sdb) device in my /dev folder!

Comment: .....Are you running `sudo echo` or `sudo tee`? There's a difference.

Comment: Dear God! I did it like a noob! :S Yeah, "sudo tee" did it :))) Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Linux has the [mount](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/umount.htm) and umount commands which are used to make a filesystem available to the OS then gracefully disconnect the filesystem when you're done.

EDIT: Be sure to umount the device when you're done with it.  If you don't data corruption is possible because the OS maybe in the middle of updating the filesystem and not complete the write before disconnecting.

Comment: I can't mount it because when i plug it in it's not even listed in "/dev" folder... Like never happened. After plugin "dmesg" is unchanged.